# Can java.net.SocketException: Socket closed exception occur due to windows?

Tags: java, sockets, exception, tcp

I have a hardware device and i communicate with it using TCP/IP.

While running the application, I am facing this exception (**java.net.SocketException: Socket closed**) only on Japanese computers. In Indian and German computers, it is running fine.

From the logs, I can see that the Socket connection is being established successfully.

Can you image Windows or Java or any other relevant setup causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Socket exceptions are caused by connection drops. The connection may have been dropped anywhere between the source OS, in the network layer or the target OS.

The starting point for diagnosing would be to telnet the target host /port and move layer by layer through the network stack